# Can some one tell me with an example of converter for escaping multiple white space?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

```
I am using JSF 1.2. I have gone through many post which has written coverter for jsf 2.x. Can some one help me how to write converter. I want escape multiple space . Please let me know if more details are required .
```

Problem : When I try for search a name which is having multiple space in between, It search correctly but when it shows on browser it shows only on space, i.e. I am searching for VIJAY,   123(3 SAPCES BETWEEN , AND 123) THEN it search for same when it shows on browser it trimmed space and shows VIJAY, 123 (there is 1 space between , and 123).Attaching screen shot for ref.
[image: before click on search i.e. ?]
[image: After click on search value is getting trimmed]

Comment: That has no relevance. You're using JSF 1.2 and thus a part of the JEE5 specification.

Comment: I tried custom converter as suggested but no luck.

Comment: got your problem resolved?

Comment: No Still searching for solution.

Comment: @Gimby above is problem with JSF 1.2 . In JSF 1.2 if found more than one white spaces between two words/character it trims and replace all space by white one space. Before downward any question please think once what exactly question complexity is .

Answer (score 0):

If it were a string in java, i would have done something like that:

```
stringObject.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

This method would replace all the extra white spaces with just a single whitespace

Comment: oops sorry forgot to add a '+' sign after \\s

Answer (score 0):

stringname.replaceAll("\s","   ");

u can use replaceall  method .